# Как преобразовать метку времени UNIX в time.Time?

Tags: golang, unixtimestamp

Как преобразовать [метку времени UNIX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) в объект [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time)?

Comment: За что минус?..

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что это ваш проект по созданию базы знаний Go на русском стэковерфлоу?

Comment: @PakUula, не только по Go... А что, разве нельзя?

Comment: @PakUula, вот собственно, чем я занимаюсь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english

Comment: Обычно я не люблю вопросы, на которые ответил сам вопрошающий )) Но в книге знаний я готов поучастовать - дать +1 вопросу, чтобы тот не попал под нож через полгода, и добавить свои пять копеек в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [`time.Unix()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Unix):

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    unixTime := time.Unix(1589570165, 0) // 0 - это число наносекунд

    fmt.Println(unixTime)
}
```

```
2020-05-15 22:16:05 +0300 MSK
```

**Update**

Во многих онлайн-системах метки времени возвращаются с миллсекундами, бывают даже метки времени с микросекундами. Это тоже называют метками времени UNIX. Для них в пакете `time` предусмотрены специальные функции [`time.UnixMilli`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#UnixMilli) и [`time.UnixMicro`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#UnixMicro). [Пример](https://go.dev/play/p/5qIkTkdbocX):

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    unixTimeMilli := time.UnixMilli(1589570165123)
    unixTimeMicro := time.UnixMicro(1589570165123456)

    fmt.Println("millis: ", unixTimeMilli)
    fmt.Println("micros: ", unixTimeMicro)
}
```

```
millis:  2020-05-15 19:16:05.123 +0000 UTC
micros:  2020-05-15 19:16:05.123456 +0000 UTC
```